# CMS Modx как сделать это?

Tags: php, cms, modx

**- Создать форму с полями, краткое описание новости, текст новости, изображение новости, дата публикации. При отправке формы с фронта(на сайте), в административной части сайта должна появлсяться неопубликованная новость в списке новостей, в соответствующем разделе.**

Иерархия структуры:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Для создания и отображения формы используйте Formit, для обработки введенных данных можно либо послать данные по определенному для form адресу в теге action (поместить там скрипт(в cниппете) и разобрать данные), либо использовать кастомный хук(тот же сниппет) для Formit и создать дочерний к странице "Новости" неопубликованный ресурс, используя возможности MODX API.
Вот несколько полезных ссылок:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20633684/how-to-create-a-new-document-resource-from-php
2. https://modx.pro/help/21295
3. https://docs.modx.com/current/en/extras/formit/formit.tutorials-and-examples/examples.custom-hook#switchsettings